# Which Kubernetes client-go methods are safe for concurrent calls?

Tags: go, kubernetes

The Kubernetes `client-go` package includes a [nice example](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment) of creating a single deployment using the `client-go` api.

I want to create and destroy many kubernetes resources without waiting for each http request to complete.

Is it possible to use the `client-go` api asynchronously?

Are methods like the ones below safe for concurrent calls from multiple goroutines?

```
resultPod, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").Create(desiredPod)
```

Comment: According to a reputable source in the Kubernetes slack channel: "We use shared clients everywhere in kube itself. They are goroutine safe."

Answer (score 2):

The k8s client uses `http.Client` internally which is safe to call concurrently. But it is probably wise to limit the number of concurrent API calls to a reasonable upper limit (I'd start with 4; anything above that is probably not going to improve performance much).